# plesk update fails

Tags: centos, package-management, plesk

I have a dedicated server running CentOS 5.3. I'm trying to update Plesk 9.5.2 to version 10.0.0 but update fails. I do it with yum:

```
yum update psa* --skip-broken -t
```

but it fails and I get the errors at the end:

```
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with psa-qmail
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with psa-qmail-rblsmtpd
Error: plesk-mail-qc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-pc-driver
Error: plesk-core conflicts with plesk-billing
Error: Missing Dependency: sw-engine = 2.0 is needed by package plesk-billing-6.0.4-20090625.11.noarch (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: pp-sitebuilder >= 10.3.0 is needed by package psa-10.3.0-cos5.build1012110629.18.x86_64 (plesk)
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-qc-driver
```

Is there a way that I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
$ yum update psa* --skip-broken -t -x plesk-mail-pc-driver
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to upgrade Plesk is by Plesk's autoinstaller. You can run the command /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller and proceed with the installer and perform upgrade.

However, before doing upgrade make sure that

```
 --> You have disabled all third party repo files under /etc/yum.repos.d
   --> Take the present psa, apsc data base backup
   -->and the upgrade must be done in non-business hours to avoid down time.
```

Now the part comes, what if it fails with Package dependency error.
Solution is really simple, if you face any dependancy, then manually remove that package and install the counter one from http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ .You will get all ur missing/required plesk packages in this repo grouped by your Plesk version/OS TYpe n arch.

Any further error,feel free and paste it here. I will try to figure it out and provide you the fix for that.